# Can't see container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to push a built docker image in a release pipeline.

My `docker build` task `yaml` is:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: MyRegistry
    repository: myrepo/containername
    command: build
    Dockerfile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/My.dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    arguments: '--build-arg FILE_NAME=myfile.zip'
```

My `docker push` task `yaml` is:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: MyRegistry
    repository: myrepo/containername
    command: push
```

The log says it runs this command:

```
/usr/bin/docker push ***/myrepo/containername:tag
```

The tasks reports success, but I can't see the resulting image in dockerhub.

I wonder if the `***` has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the Azure DevOps tasks and writing the commands via a python script. It was important to `docker login` inside the python script also.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as a self Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.